# how to get the element clicked in the listview (Android)

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

- I have an ListView `lvResults`
- I have an Custom ArrayAdapter which I register for the ListView:

  lvResults.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
- The Adapter holds 4 elements from which the last is an Icon.
- The Adapter has a `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method, which I create the View for every row.

The row looks like this in the end:
[image]

How can I determine if the image (worldicon) is clicked ?

I started trying this in the `onItemClick` method, but I have no clue:

```
lvResults.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
    }

});
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: Plz do not down-vote the question of the questioner before giving him suggestion

Comment: Thanks a lot Ravindra. Not understandable for me, why they downvote. Please downvoters, please argue why you downvoted.

Comment: Probably down-vote is much easier than giving answer :P

Comment: Most of the people downvotes even before reading the whole question.

Comment: @mcflysoft ..I did not get your problem..And just given the suggestion to get the Listview item is selected OR not :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your custom adapter inside `getView()` method, use `Holder` and set `onClickLister` to your `ImageView`. Try out the following code:

```
 public class Holder
{
    ImageView world;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;       
         rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, null);
         holder.world = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.world_icon); 

     holder.world.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
              // do your onClick action here
        }
     });       

    return rowView;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: upvoted. Your answer is 4 minutes earlier, you are right. Sorry.

Comment: This is not the right approach, since you will be having one instance per view inflated, and this could have memory leaks in the future if the list gets too big, the correct way to do it is to implement the click with an interface

Answer (score 2):

Add onclick listener to that imageview in your array adapter. The itemview click listener cannot identify each individual elements in the item.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(layout.your_layout,null);
            holder.worldImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(id.world_image);
holder.worldImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // perform necessary action
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks. And to notify the corresponding Activity I have to set the Activity in Adapter first. Thanks that helped.

Comment: Sorry Faa. Just realized, that Tahsinrupan was earlier. But still upvoted :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add onclick listener to world icon. In custom adapter itself you need to add onclick listener to imageview of world icon. You can give id or tag to imageview to identify which world icon is clicked.